# Call User Control method from Class File in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

How can I call a method from my user control(.ascx) file in one of the class file(.cs file)

Any ideas, how can I do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; Why? Extremely bad practice.

Comment: Its one of my requirement, can't roll back now. How can this be done?

Comment: give a reference to an instance of user-control to the class and make the user-control method public

Comment: Can you show me how?

Answer (score 2):

Give a reference to an instance of user-control to the class and make the user-control method public.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  public void MyUCMethod()
  {
  }
}

public class MyClass
{
  private MyUserControl myUC;
  public MyClass(MyUserControl uc)
  {
    myUC = uc;
  }
  public void MyClassMethod()
  {
    myUC.MyUCMethod();
  }
}
```

In the page class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyUserControl uc = (MyUserControl)LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");
  Controls.Add(uc);

  MyClass c = new MyClass(uc);
  c.MyClassMethod();
}
```

Comment: Will this line "MyUserControl uc = (MyUserControl)LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");" wont give error in class file in app_code folder.

Comment: ? `LoadControl` is a method of `System.Web.UI.Page` class.

Comment: But i am calling user control method from class file not an aspx page.

Comment: Having a user-control only makes sense in the context of a web page.